# Laravel Artisan::call() catch exception if fails

Tags: php, laravel, command, laravel-artisan

i have built a custom command on my laravel project which is called like so `php artisan cc`. It clears all the cache on website. But i doubt if it fully works, i want to know if there's a way to catch the error if one of the commands fail? and possibly display it. 
Here's my command code.

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Artisan;

class cc extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'cc';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Clears all cache';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        Artisan::call('config:clear');
        Artisan::call('config:cache');
        Artisan::call('cache:clear');
        Artisan::call('view:clear');
    }
}
```

Comment: Fyi, `php artisan config:cache` also runs `php artisan config:clear`. How/where does this command fail?

Comment: @kerbholz I know, both of them doesn't seem to work on production. That's why i put both of them in there

Comment: @kerbholz The permissions are correct on my server

Comment: @kerbholz sorry i elaborated incorrectly before. I meant the `php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan config:cache` work but only when i am calling them just the way they are. They don't work inside my command

Comment: Ok, no problem, might have misread that. My questions still apply though: what errors do you get when running your command? Are you _sure_ they don't work? How do you check?

Comment: The deal is for example i get the google captcha key through `env()` function which gets the value from the `.env` file. When i push the new version of the website it dissapears and the recaptcha key is null. But it gets fixed when i call `php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan cache:clear`. But when i call it with my command it just won't work

Comment: "_When i push the new version of the website it dissapears and the recaptcha key is null._" Now that sounds strange, there might be something "wrong" with your deployment process or the way you get that value - the cached config should still be present with your value. Anyway, _if_ Artisan commands throw an exception you can catch them with a `try..catch` - which wouldn't help much since the commands won't get executed anyway. Sorry I can't be of much help here